# CloudFormation - Dynamically Generate Description

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I Have a CloudFormationScript that has its definition thus:

> {
>   "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
>   "Description": "My Cluster-GREEN",
>   ...

I wanted to generate the -GREEN above dynamically via parameters I am passing in to the CFT via Parameters (BLUE/GREEN). How would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the official documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-description-structure.html),

> The value for the description declaration must be a literal string that is between 0 and 1024 bytes in length. You cannot use a parameter or function to specify the description.

So, you cannot pass the description dynamically using parameters.

If you are using SDK, there is a work around. Since, CFn template is a JSON, you can set the description with what ever value you want before calling the createStack method.

Pseudo code:

```
Map<String, Object> template = readTemplateFromResources();
template["description"] = "My Cluster-GREEN";

createStackRequest.setTemplateBody(template.toString());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I really needed to do this as part of CFT. Thanks for the clarification though.